# What other constraints does layout_constraintGuide_percent require

Tags: android

I have a ConstraintLayout containing two custom text views. When I try using a percentage it causes the app to crash with a complaint about a null anchor. However the anchors seem valid to me.

I've been through a process of trial and error and no attempt has avoided the crash (for example removing `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b"` or setting it to `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`)

**The Layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.custom.TextInputView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/c_notshown_in_example"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

<com.custom.TextInputView
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/u2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/u2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/a"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/a" />
```

**The Crash:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintAnchor.getFinalValue()' on a null object reference
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.horizontalSolvingPass(Direct.java:328)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:254)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:693)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:160)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:291)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
> a
> at

**What horizontal constraints does the percentage usage require?** (since it fails at horizontalSolvingPass)

Comment: layout_constraintGuide_percent is used with Guideline. What about using weights in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the constraints on your `@+id/a` view:

- The correct percentage constraint is `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`
- You should use `0dp` for the width when using percents
- You should constrain both sides of the view to the parent (to define the width is a percentage *of*)

Once you've done that, you will also have to add *bias* to the view in order to position it on the far left of the screen:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
```

Altogether, your first view should look like this:

```
<com.custom.TextInputView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/c_notshown_in_example"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.45"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0" />
```

Comment: It _seems_ that you can omit both the end constraint and the bias constraint and it will still work. This feels a little odd to me: how does the view know what targets to use to compute a 45% width? But perhaps the percentage constraint puts in some default targets for the start/end unless you override them?

Answer (score 1):

The idea will be to wire the `ConstraintLayout` to the `Guideline` and everything beside that (e.g. TextView etc.) to the `ConstraintLayout` for a responsive design.

My example shows it with 2 `TextView` that are exactly 80% vertically for instance and 45% and 55% in `width` (`app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45"`). Important is to set the `TextViews` `width` and `height` to `0dp` and to attach to the `Guideline`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Vertical Guideline for Text1 (here e.g. 45%) -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

    <!-- Horizontal Guideline for both Texts (here e.g. 80%)-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <!-- TextView1 in Blue -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#2962FF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TextView1 in Blue 45%" />

    <!-- TextView2 in Orange -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF6D00"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TextView2 in Orange 55%" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RESULT:**

[image: Now you have 45% and 55% in width]

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are better for examples and each outline part of the fix. This answer is to be explicit about the *reason* this error is thrown

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintAnchor.getFinalValue()' on a null object reference`

The crash happens because of using the following constraint without an anchor guide

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45"
```

The most trivial fix is to replace with the non-guide version

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.45"
```